# Which Progress datatypes correspond to which SQL Server datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, types, openedge, progress-db

I need to import data from a Progress server to a SQL Server. As an intermediate step, I need to figure out the corresponding datatypes of the fields in the Progress server. I'm not having much luck finding this online. Does anyone have a table of the equivalent datatypes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the progress docs here: http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16074
 the "SQL Development" doc has the following ABL/SQL data type mapping:

```
ABL Type    SQL Type

ARRAY       ARRAY, VARARRAY
BLOB        LVARBINARY, BLOB
CHARACTER   VARCHAR, CHAR
CLOB        CLOB, LVARCHAR
DATE        DATE
DATETIME    TIMESTAMP
DATETIME-TZ TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
DECIMAL     DECIMAL or NUMERIC
INTEGER     INTEGER
LOGICAL     BIT
RAW         VARBINARY
RECID       INTEGER
```